# Time and Space complexity of String Permutation using Set

Tags: java

this is a famous problem, but I have just started to study time and space complexity.
This is my implementation and i like to know if I'm right or not.

```
 public static void main (String[]args){
    String s1 = "Ciao";
    String s2 = "ciAo";
    String s3 = "Fratfem";

    if (s1.length() == s2.length()){
        if(permutation(s1,s2))
            System.out.println("Correct");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not same length");
    }
}


public static boolean permutation(String s1, String s2){
    String s = s1.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) + s2.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    Set<Character>set = new HashSet<>();
    for (Character c: s.toCharArray()){
        set.add(c);
    }

    if (set.size() == s1.length())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Convention : s1.length + s2.length = n

- Worst Case Space Complexity: I think it's equal to O(n*2).
- Worst Case Time Complexity: O(n) because we have to add all, and check, all characters.

I'd like to know if i am wrong, thanks.

Comment: please, describe the problem that you tried to solve with this code

Comment: I think the algorithm doesn't check out. If a word has a repeating letter, it will never be able to be considered a permutation of another word. For example `feet` and `fete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong in just about every way.

### Your algorithm is flat out broken.

For example, "CIIO" and "IICO" are not considered equal, even though one is clearly a permutation of the other. Your algorithm prints nothing if the strings are of equal length but not a permutation (which is weird output).

### This algorithm does not have the time/space complexities you mentioned.

Where are you getting `O(n^2)` from?

The main method doesn't do any looping at all, other than invoking permutation once, so we don't need to look at it.

permutation will first craft a new string by concatenating the 2 input strings; this takes `n` time and `n` space (`s1` and `s2` can't be collected nor can `s`, they're all in memory as long as permutation is running). You then loop over each character in it, which is also `O(n)`. You then invoke size and length, both `O(1)` (i.e. ignorable) operations.

So, you have `O(n)`, and then `O(n)`, which is just `O(n)`. (Because it's `O(2n)`, and `O(n)` means: "If you feed this algorithm data that is incrementally more complicated, as defined by 'having incrementally higher n', and you graph 'n' against 'time/space taken', then eventually, at some unknown point, the graph starts looking like the graph `y = x` does.

`y = 2x` looks just like `y = x`, hence why saying something is `O(2n)` is useless and therefore not correct. That just becomes `O(n)`. Same reason `O(2n^2 + 1000n)` is just `O(n^2)`. Because `y = 2x^2 + 1000n`, eventually, looks exactly like `y = x^2` does.

### How would one write the correct algorithm?

Depends on what you mean by permutation. Presumably, if shuffling letters around for one of the strings lets you make the second, i.e. `ciio` and `iico` are permutation-wise equal, but `ccio` and `ciio` are not, nor are `cio` and `ccio`.

In that case:

- Turn s1 into a char array. (`O(n)`).
- Sort this char array using `Arrays.sort`, which is `O(n logn)` - but you'd have to know that this is the performance characteristic of sort.
- Do the same to s2. (`O(n)` + `O(n logn)`).
- Check that the 2 arrays are equal. (`O(n)`).

That sums up to 2 `O(n logn)` and a whole bunch of `O(n)`, which just becomes `O(n logn)`. It becomes quite easy to 'add them up', you're just looking for the most significant factor; any factors of lesser significance are irrelevant, as are constant repeats of the most complex fcator.